# Catalan number sequence problem

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I have a hw problem where I am asked explain why $50 - 20\sqrt{6}$ which is equal to $1.01020514\cdots $ looks like a Catalan Sequence (decimal part)
How would I even begin to explain this? My usual approach to problems like this is write out a few small cases and then generalize and explain. But something like this, I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How would I explain why 50 - 20 sqrt 6 follows the Catalan Number Sequence?

Comment: $50-20\sqrt 6$ is a constant.  It doesn't follow any sequence at all.

Comment: I wonder if generating functions will be useful

Comment: It results to 1.01020414.....So I have to explain why the part after the decimal looks like a Catalan sequence. I hope it is clesr this time.

Comment: @pjs36 How would you write a generating function for it? Like that was the topic we studied last week so maybe this looks like a problem of it.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The generating function for $C_i$ is $\frac {1-\sqrt {1-4x}}2$ so just evaluate at $x=.01$

Comment: I wonder what the government of Spain thinks about Catalan numbers now. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The generating function for the Catalan numbers is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
c(x)=1+x+2x^2+5x^3+14x^4+ \cdots = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute $x= \frac{1}{100}$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
1.01020514 \cdots = 50-20\sqrt{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&1&+&x&+&2x^2&+&5x^3&+&14x^4&+& \cdots &=& \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x} \\ 
=&1&+&0.01&+&0.0002&+&0.000005&+&0.00000014&+& \cdots &=& 50-20\sqrt{6}. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Do we set the x = 0.01 because the numbers start from the second position? Could you help me understand the choice for x? I was able to derive the Catalan sequence but how do you determine what x to take?

Comment: Thanks to everyone.